# Convert a column from textfile into set using Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert one set column from multiple files into Set. I am getting the result but it seems that this code considers the whole column from each file as one set element and hence does not remove any duplicates.

I think I am not able to convert or vectorize individual elements from one file so it is grouping the column as single element.

```
import scala.io.Source


if (args.length > 0){

var ids : Set[String] = collection.immutable.HashSet()
    for (arg<-args){
ids += Source.fromFile(arg).getLines().filterNot(_.trim.startsWith("#")).map(_.split("\t")(0)).mkString("\n")
}
println(ids)
}

else
Console.err.println("Please enter filename")
```

Input files

**File a:

```
#df
ABC 2
ABC 7
CVF 9
```

**File b:

```
#dsdff
#
#
ABC 1
DFG 2
CVF 3
```

What I get is this output

```
Set(ABC
DFG
CVF, ABC
ABC
CVF)
```

Desired output:

```
Set(ABC,DFG,CVF)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `mkstring` operation being called on each file's contents and change `ids +=` to `ids ++=` (since you're adding a collection).

Or you can clean it up a bit in this way:

```
val ids: Set[String] = 
  args.flatMap { arg =>
    Source.fromFile(arg).getLines()
      .filterNot(_.trim.startsWith("#"))
      .map(_.split("\t").head)
  }.toSet
```

or like this:

```
val ids: Set[String] = 
  (for {
    arg <- args
    line <- Source.fromFile(arg).getLines()
    if !line.trim.startsWith("#")
  } yield line.split("\t").head).toSet
```